# Difficulties programming Arduino uno for 24 hour cycle

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to program my Arduino Uno board for a 24 hour cycle.
I have the Arduino board and two relays.
The aim is; every 24 hours relay 1 has to switch on for 5 seconds, and 1 second later relay 2 has to switch on for 15 seconds.
I have a sketch for a 12 hour cycle, and that works fine, but when I try for a 24 hour cycle, by changing the const unsigned int totalTime from 43200 seconds to 86400 seconds, everything goes wrong.

24 hour sketch - what is wrong?

```
//turn relays on and off at certain times.
//when the digital output pin is HIGH, then the relay is off.
//when the digital output pin is LOW, then the relay is on.

enum actioEnum {
  RELAY1_ON,
  RELAY1_OFF,
  RELAY2_ON,
  RELAY2_OFF,
};

struct tableStruct{
  unsigned int time;
  actionEnum action;
}
const table [] = {
  {0,RELAY1_ON},
  {5,RELAY1_OFF},
  // remaining 86395 for a total of 86400.
  {0,RELAY2_OFF}, // not needed, it is already off.
  {6,RELAY2_ON},
  {6+15,RELAY2_OFF},
  // remaining 86379 for a total of 86400.
};

const unsigned int totalTime = 86400; // total amount for sequence
unsigned int seconds;

unsigned long previousMillis;
const unsigned long interval = 1000; // 1000 ms; // 1000 ms is one second

const int relay1Pin = 2;
const int relay2Pin = 3;

void setup() {
   serial.begin(9600);

  // the relay is off when the pin is high.
  // turn output high before setting the pinMode.
  // then the output changes from a floating pin to high,
  // and the relays will not be activated.
  digitalWrite (relay1Pin, HIGH);
  pinMode (relay1Pin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite (relay2Pin, HIGH);
  pinMode (relay2Pin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop () {
  // a one second timer with millis
  if (millis() - previousMillis >= interval) {
    previousMillis += interval;    
    // scan table
    for ( int i = 0; i < int (sizeof(table) / sizeof (tableStruct)); i++) {
      if (table [i] . time == seconds) {
        switch (table [i] . action) {    
          case RELAY1_ON:
            Serial.println("Relay 1 on");
            digitalWrite (relay1Pin, LOW); // low is relay on.
            break;
          case RELAY1_OFF:
            Serial.println("Relay 1 off");
            digitalWrite (relay1Pin, HIGH); // high is relay off.
            break;
          case RELAY2_ON:
            Serial.println("Relay 2 on");
            digitalWrite (relay2Pin, LOW); // low is relay on.
            break;
          case RELAY2_OFF:
            Serial.println ("Relay 2 off");
            digitalWrite (relay2Pin, HIGH); // high is relay off.
            break;    
          default:
            Serial.println ("Error, a bug in the scketch");
        }
      }
    }
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= totalTime) {
      seconds = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why you are not using a RTC module?

Comment: The Uno isn't the most accurate in time keeping, and can drift by a few minutes every day. Depending on your application this might not matter. However, if it does, use an RTC like newbie suggested.

Answer (score 5):

On the Uno `unsigned int` is a 16 bit number. That means, that it can hold values between (and including) 0 and 65535. If you try to write a bigger value to this variable, it will cut of the higher bits, so that the rest fits into 16 bits. That gives you a totally different value, which is significantly small than 24h.

The solution is to use a bigger variable type for `totalTime`.
 You can use `unsigned long`, which has 32 bits and can hold way bigger values ( 0 to 4,294,967,295 (2^32 - 1)). That should be plenty enough for all your cases.

Comment: Hi, your solution is to use unsigned long instead of totalTime. how do I change this in my sketch? Regards, Martinus.

Comment: No, not instead of `totalTime`, but as the type of it. In your sketch you wrote `const unsigned int totalTime = 86400;`, but instead you should write `const unsigned long totalTime = 86400;`. That changes the type of the variable `totalTime` from `unsigned int` to `unsigned long`.